# Simpler form for $x^2 + y^2 \le 2y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to express this inequality in a simpler way, something like $a<x<b$, $g(x)<y<h(x)$. Is there any method I can use to solve it?

Inequality:
$$x^{2}+y^{2} \le 2y$$

Comment: You can draw a picture of $x^2+y^2=2y$ and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2\leqslant 2y\Longleftrightarrow x^2+y^2-2y+1\leqslant 1\Longleftrightarrow x^2+(y-1)^2\leqslant 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality in question describes a circle. To see this, rewrite it as
$$x^2 + y^2 - 2y \le 0$$

Then, remembering the identity ${(a + b)}^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ we can rewrite it as
$$x^2 + (y - 1)^2 \le 1$$

Observe that the quantity on the LHS is the Euclidean distance (squared) of the point $(x, y)$ from the point $(0, 1)$. It's clear now that the inequality is satisfied by the points that are distant less than $1$ from the point $(0, 1)$. This is a circle with center $(0, 1)$ and radius $1$.

To obtain the form you require, observe that all the $x$'s of the points in the circle satisfy $-1 \le x \le 1$. Then, inverting the inequality gives
$$1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2} \le y \le 1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$